# Laplace Transform of $f^{-1}(t)$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, inverse-function

I came across this differential equation $f'(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ on the web, and thought can we do that by a Laplace transform?

But then I got stuck on seeing any clear idea on finding  the Laplace transform for $f^{-1}(x)$.

I tried to approach it by differentiating the relation $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ and then using its result in the $\mathcal{L}\{y(t)\} = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}y(t)\,dt$ and then maybe try integration by parts (since I have some form of the derivative of $f^{-1}(x)$ ). But that doesn't seem to work out so well.

So the question is:

> If you know the Laplace transform of $f(t)$,   $\mathcal{L} \{ f(t)\} = Y(s)$, Can you find the Laplace transform of $f^{-1}(t)$ in terms of $Y(s)$ ?

BTW: The question is not about solving the DE I talked about, I did find out how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no formula like that.  In general, Laplace transforms are useful only for linear differential equations.  This one is nonlinear.